# React. Rerendering nested array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am building quiz app and there is a problem that i have to shuffle question options but they are located in the nested question array. Here is the interface:

```
export interface IConnectionsQuestionData extends IQuestionData {
    type: 'connections';
    questionsTitle: string;
    answersTitle: string;

    pairs: {
        questionOption: IConnectionsOption;
        answerOption: Maybe<IConnectionsOption>;
    }[];
} 

export interface IConnectionsOption {
    key: IDType;
    value: string;
    type: 'answer' | 'question'
}
```

So in order to shuffle options i have created custom `useShuffle` hook:

```
export const useShuffle = <T>(array: T[]): T[] => {
    return useMemo(() => {
        return shuffleArray(array);
    }, [array]) 
}
```

In `Question` component I get `question` from props. I use this hook like this:

```
 const shuffledLeftSideOptions = useShuffle(question?.pairs.map(pair => pair.questionOption) ?? [])
 const shuffledRightSideOptions = useShuffle(question?.pairs.map(pair => pair.answerOption) ?? [])
```

But every time component need to be rerendered when i choose the option, options array shuffles again on every render. I tried to test it and it works fine with `pairs` array but reshuffles with `question` or `answer` options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've only memoized the shuffling, not the `map` operation. So you get a new array every time, because `map` produces a new array every time, and so `useShuffle` has to do its work every time.

If you need to do the `map`, you'll need to memoize that as well, e.g.:

```
const mappedLeftOptions = useMemo(
    () => question?.pairs.map((pair) => pair.questionOption) ?? [],
    [question]
);
const mappedRightOptions = useMemo(
    () => question?.pairs.map((pair) => pair.answerOption) ?? [],
    [question]
);
const shuffledLeftSideOptions = useShuffle(mappedLeftOptions);
const shuffledRightSideOptions = useShuffle(mappedRightOptions);
```

**But**, beware that the memoization provided by `useMemo` provides only a **performance optimization**, not a **semantic guarantee**. (More in [the documentation](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useMemo).) But your shuffling code is relying on it as though it were a semantic guarantee.

Instead, when you need a semantic guarantee, use a ref:

```
export const useShuffle = <T>(array: T[]): T[] => {
    const arrayRef = useRef<T[] | null>(null);
    const shuffleRef = useRef<T[] | null>(null);
    if (!Object.is(array, arrayRef.current)) {
        shuffleRef.current = null;
    }
    if (!shuffleRef.current) {
        arrayRef.current = array;
        shuffleRef.current = shuffleArray(array);
    }
    return shuffleRef.current;
};
```

Or it's probably cleaner with a single ref:

```
export const useShuffle = <T>(array: T[]): T[] => {
    const ref = useRef<{ array: T[]; shuffled: T[] } | null>(null);
    if (!ref.current || !Object.is(ref.current.array, array)) {
        ref.current = {
            array,
            shuffled: shuffleArray(array),
        };
    }
    return ref.current.shuffled;
};
```

Comment: Thank you! It felt like `useMemo` was a bad idea when i made this hook, but I didn't know how to implement it in the better way.